# Unmount OverlaysFS directory with multiple lower directory

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, umount, overlayfs

There are multiple directory mounted with physical device.

```
lower0 -> /dev/blk/sda-0
lower1 -> /dev/blk/sda-1
lower2 -> /dev/blk/sda-2
lower3 -> /dev/blk/sda-3
```

Then I stacked them together using using overlayfs as shown below

`__mount(source=overlay,target=/lower3,type=overlay,lowerdir=/lower3:/lower2:/lower1:lower0)`

```
============ lower3 
============ lower2
============ lower1
============ lower0
```

I need to unmount the stack without loosing the content of each directory.

Calling umount on each directory it looses the content and can't be accessed without remounting.

Is there a way to unmount the stack while keeping the individual directory content?